# arm-none-eabi-gdb on stm32: warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response

Tags: gdb, stm32

I'm using the command-line to do my stm32 development. CubeIDE and Atom are too heavyweight for the specs of my machine.

I compile an elf and bin file with debug support and upload the bin to the stm32. It is a simple LED blink program, and it works.

I start `stlink-server`, and it reports port 7184. In another terminal I type:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb
file app.elf
target remote localhost:7184
```

I do not get a response for about 30 seconds, then `arm-non-eabi-gdb` reports:

```
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
```

`stlink-server` reports:

```
Error: recv returned 0. Remote side has closed gracefully. Good.
```

But not good!

**So, what do I do?** I can't seem to halt the stm32, set breakpoints, run, etc..

I'm running a mish-mash of stlink-server, arm-none-eabi-gcc, and arm-none-eabi-gdb from various sources, which might not be helping.

I'm using a Chinese ST-LINK v2, which I hear might not have all the pins wired up for debugging, and that I have to short some pins. It uploads the bin OK, though.

---

**Update 1** OK, perhaps a little progress (??)

I start `st-util`, which reports:

```
2020-07-06T14:50:03 INFO common.c: F1xx Medium-density: 20 KiB SRAM, 64 KiB flash in at least 1 KiB pages.
2020-07-06T14:50:03 INFO gdb-server.c: Listening at *:4242...
```

So then in a separate console I type:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:4242
(gdb) file app.elf
(gdb) load app.elf
You can't do that when your target is `exec'
```

Oh. Also:

```
(gdb) r
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
```

So I think I'm getting closer, It *appears* that I can set breakpoints. And maybe I've run the commands in the wrong order.

I think maybe I have to do:

```
exec app.elf
```

but that doesn't seem to respect the breakpoints.

Hmmm.

---

**Update 2** The saga continues.

This seems better:

```
$ $arm-none-eabi-gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:4242
(gdb) file app.elf
(gdb) b 26
continue
```

That seems to respect breakpoints; but the debugger reports:

```
Continuing.
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0800000c in _reset ()
(gdb) print i
No symbol "i" in current context
```

Hmmm. It seems that the program is now no longer in `main()`, but in a signal trap, and hence `i` is not in current context (even though I defined it it `main`).

So reaching a breakpoint basically causes the machine to reset?? Which kinda defeats the point of debugging. So I think I must be doing something wrong (?) and there's a better way of doing it?

---

**Update 3**

I switched to the Arduino IDE and uploaded a sketch. Using the procedure above, I didn't get the signal trap problem. I was able to debug my program, set breakpoints, and inspect variables. Nice. The Arduino is obviously incorporating some "secret sauce" that I had not added to my own non-Arduino code.

So, it mostly works. Mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Try reset mcu before load:

```
target remote localhost:4242
file app.elf
monitor reset halt
load app.elf
```